# Dynamically initialize multiple data sources in Spring

Tags: spring, routes, datasource

In my spring application , I need to dynamically initialize multiple data sources based on some values set up in the application configuration.
I am aware of the AbstractRoutingDataSource class provided by spring jdbc library but it helps only when you need to initialize a single data source based on a single look up key value at a time.

Is it possible to extend the AbstractRoutingDataSource and change its behavior to support multiple key look up and data source resolution? Is there any other alternative approach ? [Reference](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

Basically I am trying to achieve something like this through AbstractDataSourceRouter class:

```
public class DataSourceRouter extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {


@Value("${com.listdb.datasource.switch}")
private short listDBSwitch;

@Value("${com.scoringdb.datasource.switch}")
private short scoringDbSwitch;

@Value("${com.configmaster.datasource.switch}")
private short configDbSwitch;


private List<String> configuredDataSources;
/**
 * Determine the current lookup key. This will typically be
 * implemented to check a thread-bound transaction context.
 * <p>Allows for arbitrary keys. The returned key needs
 * to match the stored lookup key type, as resolved by the
 * {@link #resolveSpecifiedLookupKey} method.
 */
@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {

    if(ListUtil.isListNotEmpty(configuredDataSources)) {

        configuredDataSources =new ArrayList<String>();


        String listDBString = (listDBSwitch == 1)?DataSources.LIST.toString() : null;
        String configDBString = (configDbSwitch == 1) ? DataSources.CONFIGMASTER.toString() :null;
        String scoringDBString = (scoringDbSwitch == 1) ? DataSources.SCORING.toString() : null;

        /**
         * Add all configured data source keys for look up
         */
        configuredDataSources.add(listDBString);
        configuredDataSources.add(configDBString);
        configuredDataSources.add(scoringDBString);

    }

    return configuredDataSources;
}
```

}

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible with current spring/hibernate versions even if it would be neat to have it that way. If you need multiple data sources and use AbstractRoutingDataSource to achieve this, then one possible solution is to let spring initialize one DB (the default/configuration DB) and add e.g. init.sql script (or flyway/liquibase such if you are more into that) that initializes all other under the same AbstractRoutingDataSource.

This approach works nicely and gives you more control over your (hopefully test!) environment. Personally I like to have more control over DB schema then any auto-initializers can provide, however that's only a taste/style issue.